# Previous button not working properly jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery mobile I am trying to create app with jquery mobile I am facing two problems with this as listed below,

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nikkirs/pfxyLqLh/18/)

1. I have 30 Q. per page I am showing 5 Q. but when I click next to
   15th Q and then click to previous it takes me to 2nd to 6th Q.
2. If I went till 10th Q and click on back button it takes me to main screen
   after again I click on HTML5 it should take me to 1 st 5 Q but it's
   sticking to Q which I visited before So while coming back and going
   again to same tab it should get refresh and show Divs from starting

Pls help me in this I tried this much here is example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var i=5;
    $("#html5 .collapsible").hide().slice( i-5, i ).show();
    var j = 20
$(".ui-block-b").click(function() {

    $('.ui-block-a input[type="button"]').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('.ui-btn').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
$("#html5 .collapsible").hide().slice( j-15, j-10 ).show();
    j+=5;

if($('#html5 .collapsible:last').is(':visible')) {
        $('.ui-block-b input[type="button"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
        $('.ui-block-b .ui-btn').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
    }
});

$(".ui-block-a").click(function() {
var b = $("#html5 .collapsible:visible:last").index();
//alert(b);
  $('.ui-block-b input[type="button"]').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('.ui-btn').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
if($('#html5 .collapsible:first').is(':visible')) {
        $('.ui-block-a input[type="button"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
        $('.ui-block-a .ui-btn').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
    } 
else{
$("#html5 .collapsible").hide().slice( b-9, b-4 ).show();
    b+=5;
}
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used multiple variable to keep track to visible elements on click of Previous and Next button, instead you can use only one variable (in your case it is `i`) and increment / decrement it accordingly.

To resolve your second problem, I have added `resetPage` function that will get called when page loads and when user clicks on HTML button.

Use `i` to make decision for disabling Previous / Next button. see below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var i=0;
  resetPage = function(){
      i=0;
      $("#html5 .collapsible").hide().slice( i, i+5 ).show();
      //disable previous button by default 
      $('.ui-block-a .ui-btn').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
      $('.ui-block-a .ui-btn input[type="button"]').attr('disabled');
  }

   //call it on page load    
   resetPage();

   //bind click event for html button
   $('.ui-content .ui-btn-up-c').click(function(){
      resetPage();    
   });


   $('.ui-block-b .ui-btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.ui-block-a .ui-btn').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
        $('.ui-block-a .ui-btn input[type="button"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        i+=5;
        $("#html5 .collapsible").hide().slice( i, i+5 ).show();

        if(i==(j-5))
        {
            $('.ui-block-b .ui-btn').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
            $('.ui-block-b .ui-btn input[type="button"]').attr('disabled');
        }
    });

    $('.ui-block-a .ui-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     $('.ui-block-b .ui-btn').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
     $('.ui-block-b .ui-btn input[type="button"]').removeAttr('disabled');

     i-=5;
     $("#html5 .collapsible").hide().slice( i, i+5 ).show();

     if(i==0)
     {
        $('.ui-block-a .ui-btn').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
        $('.ui-block-a .ui-btn input[type="button"]').attr('disabled');
      }
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pfxyLqLh/41/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot thanku so much for this can you find any way for my second Query